# select the result of describe table or show columns in databricks SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to run a query that will give an output if a particular column is present in table and if not then give some other value. I tried the below query:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'Country' in (SHOW COLUMNS FROM myDB.myTable)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END AS isCountryPresent,
           *
    FROM myDB.myTable
```

but this gives an error. I can only use Databricks SQL. is there a way to access the result of `SHOW COLUMNS` or `DESCRIBE TABLE` in a SELECT statement? The error can be see here:
[image: here]

Comment: You are missing the `CASE` before the `WHEN`

Comment: Ah my bad, I have made the edit in the question.

Comment: If working with a dataframe is an option you can do something like `df.withColumn('isCountryPresent', f.lit('Country' in df.columns))`.  For sql not sure if its possible

Answer (score 0):

You should use PySpark API instead of Spark SQL API

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.table('myDB.myTable')

df.withColumn('isCountryPresent', F.when(F.lit('Country').isin(df.columns), 1).otherwise(0)).show()
```

Comment: Thank for this approch. However in my case I can only use sql api.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.frunctions import w
#to use direct dataframe
df1 = df.withcolumn(‘dataframe name’, w.when(w.lit(‘Country’).isin(df.columns),1).otherwise(0)))

#to mention table in pyspark API
```

A DataFrame is similar as the relational table in Spark SQL, can be created using various function in SQLContext.
Convert the existing table into the dataframe and use the syntax

```
df1 = df.withcolumn(‘dataframe name’, w.when(w.lit(‘Country’).isin(df.columns),1).otherwise(0)))
```

Comment: This works in pyspark api approch but I am using databricks sql and can only use sql queries.